# Android mask image

Tags: android, mask, android-image

I have two images in my `Drawable` folder.

I want to mask image1 with image2 so that I get round edges for image1.

How can I achieve this? I saw some solutions with bufferedimage and `getRGB`.Is there any easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take ImageView
2. Set the border/frame 9-patch image as `android:background`
3. Now set the actual image to the ImageView as `android:src`

Example of 9-patch frame:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to directly create an rounded corners ImageView following the code from here 
[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)